# Not able to read aliexpress.com via php

Tags: php

I'm trying to read aliexpress.com deals page via php. I'm not able to get the details of the page in output.

Is there a way I can get the details.

Below is the code.

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $url = 'http://activities.aliexpress.com/superdeals.php';
    $xml = file_get_html($url);
    //$file = 'output1.txt';
    $element = $xml;
    echo $element;
?>
```

Comment: Done any basic debugging? Like skipping simplehtml and doing `var_dump(file_get_contents('http://....'))` to see the raw returned data?

Comment: That page is rendered by javascript, probably specifically to disallow what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This website used [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)
There are two solutions :

- Make the same request as Javascript
- Using a tool like [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

If you look at requests, you will find easily that a GET request is made and return all information in JSON.
So you need to find by yourself the link or use third party library + tools.

EDIT:

You can use your web browser to get the link (I don't give you it because i think stackoverflow is not for that) with [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) or if you're using chrome, in network tab search for the JSON.

```
$url = "....";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
if($str) {
    $json = json_decode($str, true); // json is an array
    // ... do what you need
}
```

I recommend to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) for many reasons.

Or you can use [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) (it's really more difficult) and get a "HTML snapshot" and then use DOM or [XPATH](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to get what you need, but you must run Phantomjs and use a third party library for communicate with it.

Comment: Thanks will try and update you shortly.You have any code examples for the same?